# ¿Cómo me traigo un valor guardado en la base de datos desde un procedimiento en Delphi?

Tags: base-de-datos, delphi, firebird

Soy nueva en el uso de este lenguaje y me surgen algunas dudas. Estoy trabajando con un editor de Delphi, el cuál posee un compilador integrado. Este código es para crear una pantalla donde se pueda escribir un texto tipo descripción para casos. Lo que quiero hacer es que **cuando una persona haga click en esta pantalla para introducir información, si esta ya estuviera cargada, le trajera la información**, en caso contrario, traería el formulario en blanco. Dicha información se guarda en una base de datos Firebird, y el campo se llama CASO.

Este es el código únicamente de la pantalla que llevo hasta ahora:

```
    {$FORM TCasos, Ficha de Casos.sfm}       
    uses
      Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms, Dialogs, StdCtrls;


    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    begin                         

      if (Memo1.Lines.Text <> '') then
        begin                
          VCASO:= Memo1.Lines.Text;    
          Self.Close;                                      
        end                                                       
      else                   
      begin    
showmessage (''No puede dejar el campo vacío.'');   
        //Aquí quiero traerme el valor (si ya tiene)                                
      end;  
    end;      

    procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);                     
    begin
       Self.Close;
    end;

    begin                      
    end;
```

El .SQL que se genera para cargar la pantalla es este:

```
COMMIT WORK;
/*Crear los campos */

ALTER TABLE casos_ad add CASO VARCHAR (2000);

COMMIT WORK;
/*Pantalla adicional */
UPDATE OR INSERT INTO PANTALLA_ADICIONAL (CORRELATIVO, MODULO, EVENTO, CODIGO_FUENTE, FECHA_CREACION, FECHA_ULTIMA_MODIFICACION, ACTIVO, FORMA_FUENTE, CONDICION_EJECUCION)
                                  VALUES (23, 'Ficha de Casos', 'Al presionar F9', '{$FORM TCaso, Ficha de Casos.sfm}       
uses
  Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms, Dialogs, StdCtrls;


procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin                         

  if (Memo1.Lines.Text <> '''') then
    begin                
      VCASO:= Memo1.Lines.Text;    
      Self.Close;                                      
    end                                                       
  else                   
  begin                          
    showmessage (''No puede dejar el campo vacío.'');                                     
  end;  
end;      

procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);                     
begin
   Self.Close;
end;

begin                      
end;                  




', '2019-02-08', '2019-02-08', 'T', 'object Caso: TScriptForm
  Left = 5
  Top = 5
  Caption = ''Caso''
  ClientHeight = 242
  ClientWidth = 498
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = ''Tahoma''
  Font.Style = []
  OldCreateOrder = False
  Position = poDesigned
  SaveProps.Strings = (
    ''Visible=False'')
  SaveEvents.Strings = (
    ''Button1.OnClick=Button1Click''
    ''Button2.OnClick=Button2Click'')
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
  object Label1: TLabel
    Left = 8
    Top = 16
    Width = 206
    Height = 13
    Caption = ''Ingrese aqu''#237'' la descripci''#243''n de su caso:''
  end
  object Button1: TButton
    Left = 152
    Top = 200
    Width = 75
    Height = 25
    Caption = ''F9 Registrar''
    TabOrder = 0
  end
  object Button2: TButton
    Left = 256
    Top = 200
    Width = 75
    Height = 25
    Caption = ''ESC Cerrar''
    TabOrder = 1
  end
  object Memo1: TMemo
    Left = 8
    Top = 32
    Width = 473
    Height = 153
    TabOrder = 2
  end
end
', NULL)
                                ;

COMMIT WORK;
```

Mi duda es en cuanto al else, puesto que como es una pantalla que se puede generar varias veces, es posible que la misma ya este llena una segunda vez que sea consultada y en ese caso me gustaría que me trajera la información allí almacenada. Es decir, si no hay nada ahi guardado me traiga el mensaje de que no puede estar en blanco pero en caso contrario (si este campo ya fue guardado) pueda consultarlo.

Así luce el entorno que utilizo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola. Para aclarar un poco, no puedes escribir texto en un _compilador_. Quizás te refieres a un editor (¿no utilizas el IDE de Delphi?), pues el _compilador_ es la parte específica de Delphi que (valga la redundancia) compila tu programa. Es decir, que interpreta el código fuente que escribiste y, si es válido, produce una representación de código objeto del mismo, generalmente en forma de un ejecutable o una biblioteca de acceso dinámico (dll).

Comment: Ahora, para ir a tu pregunta, es promordial saber cómo te conectas a Firebird, al menos el nombre del componente con el que te conectas, pues hay diferentes capas de conexión y la mecánica puede variar un poco. Luego, te sugiero que re escribas la parte donde explicas la mecánica por la que quieres obtener el valor, la he leído 2 o 3 veces y no me termina de quedar claro como quieres que funcione.

Comment: Buenas noches amigo, cambie la redacción de mi texto y agregue algunas imágenes para tratar de explicarme mejor... :) para conectarme utilizo IBExpert. Por favor avìsame si aùn quedan dudas!! @jachguate

Comment: Bienvenida a Stackoverflow. 
Dices que trabajas con IBExpert contra una Base de Datos en Firebird. Imagino que ese campo (CASO) pertenece a una tabla. 
Digamos que hay varias cosas que debe hacer para completar lo que necesitas.
Para trabajar con un campo, de una tabla, de una Base de Datos, debes crear en tu programa una conexión (IMPORTANTE) para conectar a esa B.D y a esa tabla. 
Una vez tengas la conexión ya puedes guardar/recuperar datos. Lo más sencillo es trabajar con componentes. Revisa este vídeo para hacerte una idea (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=je4zzAvUm4U).

Comment: Hola @GermánEstévez-Neftalí- muchas gracias, yo si logro conectar, de hecho con el codigo que tengo hasta ahora puedo insertar en el campo la informacion que la persona llena, este campo pertenece a una tabla adicional que guarda otros valores que la tabla original no almacena. De hecho desde IBExpert puedo consultar el contenido de la tabla y actualmente, si la persona ingresa otra vez a esa pantalla el valor que tiene guardado no me lo muestra y requiero mostrarlo. En este momento, asi yo haya registrado un valor me lo muestra vacio y si guardo otro valor se modifica en la tabla.

Comment: Ya que veo que guardas el código fuente en una base de datos, me inclino a pensar que trabajas con una especie de _framework_ que va más allá del Delphi normal y dentro del cual ya tienes una conexión establecida, pero que tu no tienes toda la información que necesitas para ejecutar la tarea que te están pidiendo. Sugiero que pidas ayuda a los creadores de ese _framework_ o que leas su documentación primero.

Comment: Hola!! efectivamente, consulte con uno de los chicos y había que hacer algunos cambios en el código. Agregar unos Enabled, entre otras cosas mil gracias!!!